# Thread and isExecuting variable

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, sleep

I'm trying to figure out how IOs manages the threads: even if the documentation doesn't recommend to use both p_thread POSIX and NSThread (in  swift just Thread) I think it is helpful to understand how they work.
I tried to make a test with the Thread class, to understand what Apple intends  by "IsExecuting variable" of the Thread class. In its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/thread/1411240-isexecuting) Apple states that this variable returns "true if the receiver is executing, otherwise false."
So I tried to create a thread that prints the moment it will go to sleep , sleeps for 5 seconds, wakes up, and prints that it woke up and repeats the cycle.

this is the code :

```
    func mythread() {
    repeat{
        print("myThread start to sleep ...")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
        print("...myThread wakes up")

    }while(true)
}
```

and another thread that every second prints the "isExecuting variable" of mythread
this is the code :

```
    func threadmonitor(){
    repeat{
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        print("     myThread isExecuting? : \(myThread!.isExecuting)")
    }while (true)
}
```

the prints are the following:

```
myThread start to sleep ...
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 ...myThread wakes up
 myThread start to sleep ...
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
 myThread isExecuting? : true
```

why, even when the thread "MyThread" sleeps, its "isExecuting variable" prints true?
What does then Apple intend by Executing? At this point I do not believe that it intends that the thread is running in the processor.

in this case what does it intend?

Comment: Not only do they not recommend doing `p_thread` with `NSThread`/`Thread`, with the advent of GCD, they suggest you consider abandoning your own thread programming entirely. See [Concurrency Programming Guide: Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1). Sure, use it if you must, but life is much easier with GCD than it was with `NSThread`.

Comment: In answer to your question, I believe it's telling you that the thread has been started and hasn't terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping still counts as executing. The thread has started and has not yet finished.

Note that iOS generally does not manage its threads via `NSThread`. It mostly works with queues (via `NSOperationQueue` and GCD) which are built on top of threads implemented with pthreads. `NSThread` is *also* built on top of pthreads, but its use is, as you say, generally discouraged.